# Как через JS поменять aria-label и подобные атрибуты

Tags: javascript, html

Здравствуйте у меня есть кнопка меню, как поменять текст aria-label? при клике

```js
let menuIcon = document.querySelector(".h-nav-toggler");

menuIcon.addEventListener("click", () => {
  menuIcon.classList.toggle("h-nav-toggler_active");
});
```

```html
<button type="button" class="header__nav-toggler h-nav-toggler" aria-label="Открыть меню" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="h-nav-toggler__line"></span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте для этого [Element.setAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)

```js
const menuIcon = document.querySelector(".h-nav-toggler");

menuIcon.addEventListener("click", () => {
    menuIcon.classList.toggle("h-nav-toggler_active");
    menuIcon.setAttribute("aria-label", "Some new string");
    console.log(menuIcon.getAttribute("aria-label"));
});
```

```html
<button type="button" class="header__nav-toggler h-nav-toggler" aria-label="Открыть меню" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="h-nav-toggler__line"></span>
</button>
```

Comment: спасибо, а как сделать чтоб оно работало как toggle, потому что сейчас поменяется лишь при клике, но когда повторно произойдет нажатие, текст старый не вернется

Answer (score 0):

```
let menuIcon = document.querySelector(".h-nav-toggler");

menuIcon.addEventListener("click", () => {
    menuIcon.classList.toggle("h-nav-toggler_active");
    let n = "true" === menuIcon.getAttribute("aria-expanded");
    menuIcon.setAttribute("aria-expanded", !n),
        n
            ? menuIcon.setAttribute("aria-label", "Открыть меню")
            : menuIcon.setAttribute("aria-label", "Закрыть меню");
});
```